# Рефакторинг кода в Java

Tags: java, разработка-игр, рефакторинг

Здравствуйте, пишу игру тетрис, и возникла такая проблема, что получаются очень захламленные условия, хотелось бы узнать возможно ли это как упростить более простым способом. К примеру функция, которая обрабатывает нажатие на левую кнопку(передвижение фигуры влево), в ней проверяется выход за границы поля и не было ли пересечения с другими фигурами путем прохождения циклом по всему списку фигур кроме последней фигуры(которой я управляю), если все в порядке то происходит перемещение влево на 50, вот собственно код, и таких функция у меня уже 4-6(Вопрос очень актуальный для меня)

```
private void handleLeftKeyPressed(LinkedList<Figure> listFigure){
    if(keyInputListener.isLeftPressed()){
        boolean tmp = false;
        if(listFigure.getLast().getPositionX() >= beginX) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFigure.size() - 1; i++){
                if((listFigure.get(i).getPositionX() + listFigure.get(i).getWidth() == listFigure.getLast().getPositionX()) &&
                        ((listFigure.getLast().getPositionY() + listFigure.getLast().getHeight() + 50 >= listFigure.get(i).getPositionY() + listFigure.get(i).getHeight() / 2) && (listFigure.getLast().getPositionY() <= listFigure.get(i).getPositionY() + listFigure.get(i).getHeight()))){
                    tmp = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!tmp){
                listFigure.getLast().move(-50, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void handleLeftKeyPressed(LinkedList<Figure> listFigure){
    Figure last = listFigure.getLast();
    if(!keyInputListener.isLeftPressed() || last.getPositionX() < beginX) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < listFigure.size() - 1; i++){
        Figure current = listFigure.get(i);
        if(current.getPositionX() + current.getWidth() == last.getPositionX() 
           && last.getPositionY() + last.getHeight() + 50 >= current.getPositionY() + current.getHeight() / 2 
           && last.getPositionY() <= current.getPositionY() + current.getHeight()
           ){
            return;
        }
    }
    last.move(-50, 0);
}
```

Переименуйте методы `getPositionX` в `getX` (и про `y` тоже) - станет сильно читабельней.

В Figure добавьте методы `getRightBount` и `getBottomBound` возвращающие `x + width` и `y + height`

Условие станет таким:

```
if(current.getRightBound() == last.getX() 
   && last.getBottomBound() + 50 >= current.getY() + current.getHeight() / 2 
   && last.getY() <= current.getBottomBound()
           ) { return; }
```

Теперь его хотя бы можно анализировать не боясь сломать глаза. Подозреваю, что у вас там вместо первого `&&` должно быть `||`. Проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, должно быть логиское "И"